# MD5 etc. as a hash function

Tags: hash

Let's say you are planning to design a hash function which will generate keys between 0-256. Will using first 2 digits of MD5-digest be a great idea for a uniform distribution? What do you think on this? Is it expensive to md5() some word (2-10 letters)?

I know it is a rough definition of requirements but it would be great to discuss this.

Comment: I imagine there is no guarantee that a subset of an MD5 hash has a uniform distribution (similar to how GUIDs work).

Comment: Considering a multi-megabyte file can be MD5'ed like, well, "instantly" on modern hardware... however, with such a short input, uhh.. hmm.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you hashing two character strings to two character hashes?

Comment: I agree with David. You're probably best off just writing up a quick test app that runs your design several thousand times so you can get an idea of the cost and statistical distribution.

Comment: If you are looking for a 1 byte hash. Perhaps CRC8 will work better.

Comment: What would you use if you need to generate a lets say [0, 255] valued hash function from strings, uniformly distributed as much as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try [calculating](http://www.miscel.dk/MiscEl/CRCcalculations.html) an 8-bit [CRC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check).

Answer (score 4):

There's no reason to use a cryptographic strength hash for something as simple as generating 3 digit hashes. You're better off using a more simple hash there.

I'm not certain specifically how expensive MD5 is relative to others, but there are plenty of better ways to create a small hash (see [this article](http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/) for some algorithm ideas).

Answer (score 1):

MD5 is designed to uniformaly spread the input over all the output bytes so it's as good as any other general hash function - sounds like a bit of overkill if you only want 256 values.

Note the output of MD5 is 128bytes (16bytes), it's only the text representation that is hex digits - so there is really no first two digits of MD5 - just use the bottom 8bits.

Comment: The output of MD5 is bigger than the probable input (2-10 bytes).

Comment: Isn't that pretty much the definition of an ideal hash function ;-)   As I said MD5 is overkill for this, but if you have an MD5 function available why write your own ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't explained how you're going to use the hash, and what you're going to do with the collisions that are inevitable given that you have only 256 output values.

I think even MD5 (which is not cryptographically secure any more) is overkill for the likely applications.

I'd probably go with a [CRC](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) (cyclic redundancy check) algorithm that would generate a 16-bit or 32-bit number for you, and would likely give you good enough distribution.