# Uniform distribution of truncated md5?

Tags: hash, md5, distribution

Can we say that a truncated `md5` hash is still uniformly distributed?

To avoid misinterpretations: I'm aware the chance of collisions is much greater the moment you start to hack off parts from the `md5` result; my use-case is actually *interested* in *deliberate* collisions. I'm also aware there are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4109035/md5-etc-as-a-hash-function) [hash methods](http://www.partow.net/programming/hashfunctions/) that may be better suited to use-cases of a shorter hash (including, in fact, my own), and I'm definitely looking into those.

But I'd also really like to know whether `md5`'s uniform distribution also applies to chunks of it. (Consider it a burning curiosity.)

Since mediawiki uses it (specifically, the left-most two hex-digits as characters of the result) to generate filepaths for images (e.g. `/4/42/The-image-name-here.png`) and they're probably also interested in an at least *near*-uniform distribution, I imagine the answer is 'yes', but I don't actually *know*.

Comment: While we're here, anyone have good link to a proof of the uniformity of non-truncated md5 sums?

Comment: @naught101: Since this question is rather old (by internet measure) and has an accepted answer, it's unlikely to get much more exposure from people who could answer your question - maybe make your own question? :)

Comment: Nice follow-up: [ECDF plot from a truncated MD5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52936957/759866)

Comment: @Benjamin Awesome, thank you for the link!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, not exhibiting any bias is a design requirement for a cryptographic hash. MD5 is broken from a cryptographic point of view however the distribution of the results was never in question.

If you still need to be convinced, it's not a huge undertaking to hash a bunch of files, truncate the output and use ent ( http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/ ) to analyze the result.

Comment: Much appreciated - this is exactly the sort of answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 13):

I wrote a little php-program to answer this question. It's not very scientific, but it shows the distribution for the first and the last 8 bits of the hashvalues using the natural numbers as hashtext. After about 40.000.000 hashes the difference between the highest and the lowest counts goes down to 1%, so I'd say the distribution is ok. I hope the code is more precise in explaining what was computed :-)
Btw, with a similar program I found that the last 8 bits seem to be distributed slightly better than the first.

```
<?php
// Setup count-array:
for ($y=0; $y<16; $y++) {
  for ($x=0; $x<16; $x++) {
    $count[dechex($x).dechex($y)] = 0;
  }
}

$text = 1; // The text we will hash.
$hashCount = 0;
$steps = 10000;

while (1) {
  // Calculate & count a bunch of hashes:
  for ($i=0; $i<$steps; $i++) {   
    $hash = md5($text);
    $count[substr($hash, 0, 2)]++;
    $count[substr($hash, -2)]++;
    $text++;
  }
  $hashCount += $steps;

  // Output result so far:
  system("clear");
  $min = PHP_INT_MAX; $max = 0;
  for ($y=0; $y<16; $y++) {
    for ($x=0; $x<16; $x++) {  
      $n = $count[dechex($x).dechex($y)];
      if ($n < $min) $min = $n;
      if ($n > $max) $max = $n;
      print $n."\t";
    }
    print "\n";
  }
  print "Hashes: $hashCount, Min: $min, Max: $max, Delta: ".((($max-$min)*100)/$max)."%\n";
} 
?>
```

Comment: This is fantastic. Thank you! (I suppose I could/should have done this myself, really!)